# HTML CSS JavaScript Font on Site without use of Image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, font-face

I know of cufon and one other similar. But what is the best way to use a non web standard font as a font on your site? I have a client who has 2 distinct fonts they want to use as the text through out the site being created but they are not standard fonts for the web. I could do them as images maybe, if they were just navigation use. But they want the whole body up and down to be using these fonts through out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after some good, some bad times with cufon, i settled using @font-face and enjoy it.

if your font license allows it, http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator is a nice generator for all the needed files + some basic css.

Answer (score 2):

I think all other posts has said the same thing.  I find @font-face the best tool for alternative fonts.  If you have you own font you can use the font-squirel generator as mentioned by Roman.

But

If you  just what a wider choose of fonts you can't do any better than Google fonts - http://www.google.com/webfonts. This service easily let you add fonts to your site.

Comment: +1 for google webfonts, if only more designers would see them as a nice alternative...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how I use a font on my website.

```
@include url('http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/cssreset/reset-min.css');
@font-face { font-family: VAGLT; src: url('VAGLT.TTF'); } 
@font-face { font-family: VAGBT; font-weight: bold; src: url('VAGBT.TTF'); }

.boldtitle{
    font-family: VAGBT, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This of course is in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues to deal with here.

### Embedding

You can embed font files (OpenType, Web Open Font Format [WOFF], etc.) using CSS's `@font-face`. Different web browsers support fonts in different formats so you will need to use multiple formats to catch all the variations.

Something like the following should work:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
    url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
    url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}

body {
    font-family: MyFontFamily, /* etc. */ sans-serif;
}
```

### Legal

You ought to check the font licenses to make sure they can be used on the web. The kind of embedding shown above is broadly considered a limited form of distribution, but many font licenses are quite liberal these days.